# Recover Debian 8.7 after accidently purging essential packages

Tags: debian, system-recovery

Trying to get rid of strange startup errors I purged some of the essential packages. My xfce4 doesn't start on boot, which is not too bad, I still have the tty, but I also have no network connection, which means I can't reinstall anything.

On the bright side, I have a flash drive with Debian live, from which I originally installed the system.

Is there any way to recover my system in such circumstances. Which of course would be easier than just reinstalling the whole thing (I don't really care about any of the files on my system partition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a flash drive to your sources list. It's fairly simple:

1. mount the usb flash drive, to an arbitrary directory, e.g. `/mnt` (assuming the flash drive to be `/dev/sdb1`

   ```
   mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
   ```
2. add the mount point as apt-source: add a line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (e.g. use `vi`) that references the mount point:

   ```
   deb file:/mnt jessie main
   ```
3. run `apt-get update` and then use `apt-get install` as usual, as the flash drive is now a regular repository source
4. when done better comment out the new line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or delete it)

Side note: the distribution and components can be read from the `dists` directory on the iso. You'll e.g. find `jessie/contrib` and `jessie/main`, so the line in  `sources.list` could also be

```
deb file:/mnt jessie main contrib
```

---

Possible alternative: in case you only ruptured WLAN access, you might also try an ethernet connection.